# How do I annotate a callable with *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function which returns a function. I would like to find a proper type annotation. However, the returned function has `*args` and `*kwargs`. How is that annotated within `Callable[[Parameters???], ReturnType]`?

Example:

```
from typing import Callable
import io
import pandas as pd

def get_conversion_function(file_type: str) -> Callable[[io.BytesIO, TODO], pd.DataFrame]:
    def to_csv(bytes_, *args, **kwargs):
        return pd.read_csv(bytes_, **kwargs)
    if file_type == "csv":
        return to_csv
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I know, python's typing does not allow do that straightforwardly as stated in the docs of [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

> There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types. Callable[..., ReturnType] (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments and returning ReturnType.

But you could use  [mypy extensions](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html#extended-callable-types) like this:

```
from typing import Callable
from mypy_extensions import Arg, VarArg, KwArg

def foo(a: str, *args: int, **kwargs: float) -> str:
    return 'Hello, {}'.format(a)
    
def bar() -> Callable[[Arg(str, 'a'), VarArg(int), KwArg(float)], str]:
    return foo
```

Comment: As noted in the `mypy_extensions` docs linked above, extended callable types are now deprecated. The deprecation notice says that "You can use callback protocols as a replacement."

Answer (score 30):

With the introduction of `typing.Protocol`, MyPy (and other compliant type checkers) support the full call syntax natively via the `__call__` special method.

> #### MyPy: [Callback Protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols)
>
> Protocols can be used to define flexible callback types that are hard (or even impossible) to express using the `Callable[...]` syntax, such as variadic, overloaded, and complex generic callbacks. (...)

Simply define a `Protocol` whose `__call__` method has the desired signature.

```py
from typing import Protocol

class SomeCallable(Protocol):
      def __call__(self, a: str, b: int, *args: float, **kwargs: str) -> bytes: ...

def my_callable(a: str, b: int, *args: float, **kwargs: str) -> bytes:
    return b"Hello World"

def my_func(key: str) -> SomeCallable:
    return my_callable
```

Note that the `Protocol`'s `__call__` must include a `self` parameter. This parameter is ignored when comparing other signatures against the `Protocol`.