# Typehint a variadic function in Python

Tags: python, variadic-functions, typing

I wrote a higher-order python function (let's call it `parent`) and its parameter function (let's call it `child`) is a variadic function.

I don't know how to typehint it.

`child` takes as parameter a first argument that always is a `str` and a variable number of parameters that can be anything. It returns `Any`.

The closest I can get to it is `Callable[..., Any]` but then I "lose" the fact that the first argument is a `str`.

I would like something as such `Callable[[str,...], Any]` but this is not a valid typehint.

Is there a way to typehint my function?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65564936/476

Comment: @deceze It does. But, if I'm not mistaken, this means that I have to wrap `child` into a "typehinting wrapper" that implements `Protocol`. Does this means that there is no simpler way to achieve it ([it seems to be the case](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) does not require you to manually wrap values in a "type-hinting wrapper", but unfortunately it doesn't help you here.

If a function can match a protocol, it's signature must exactly match that of the `__call__` method in the protocol. However, (if I'm not mistaken) you want to match any function with a string as the first argument, which can be any of the following:

```
def fn1(x: str) -> Any: ...
def fn2(x: str, arg1: int, arg2: float) -> Any: ...
def fn3(x: str, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any: ...
```

these all have different signatures, and thus cannot be matched by a single protocol: ([mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=c5905e2ef0cf1dbaaa4210391ffb7d80))

```
from typing import Any, Protocol

# This might be the protocol you might use, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
class StrCallable(Protocol):
  def __call__(self, x: str, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
    ...

def my_higher_order_fn(fn: StrCallable) -> StrCallable:
  return fn  # fill this with your actual implementation

my_higher_order_fn(fn1)  # fails
my_higher_order_fn(fn2)  # fails
my_higher_order_fn(fn3)  # this passes, though
```

---

[PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) introduced `ParamSpec`, which is what you'll need here. It's kinda like `TypeVar`, but for function signatures. You can put a `ParamSpec` where you'd put the first list argument in `Callable`:

```
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
TRet = TypeVar("TRet")

StrCallable = Callable[Concatenate[str, P], TRet]
```

where `Concatenate` is concatenating types to an existing parameter spec. `Concatenate[str, P]` is exactly what you need: any function signature whose first argument is a `str`.

Unfortunately, PEP 612 won't be available until Python 3.10, and mypy does not yet fully support it either. Until then, you might have to just use `Callable[..., TRet]`.