# Python 3.9 custom type compatible to older versions

Tags: python, python-3.8, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.9

I want to substitute a custom type that works as is in Python 3.9, but breaks when one uses older versions of Python 3.8 or below:

Python 3.9:

```
from typing import Callable, Any
custom_type = Callable[[Any, ...], int]
```

Python 3.8:

```
from typing import Callable, Any
custom_type = Callable[[Any, ...], int]  
# >>> TypeError: Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type. Got Ellipsis.
```

I've tried the below examples, but they don't exactly match the original meaning of the original:

```
custom_type = Callable[..., int]  # Works but accepts any number of arguments
custom_type = Callable[[Any], int]  # Works but accepts one (finite) number of arguments
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html):

> (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments

If my interpretation of `Any` is correct, this would include 0 arguments, but I'm looking for **at least one.**

In Python 3.9, `Callable` can have an ellipsis in the list of the arguments. However, including an ellipsis throws an error for older versions (I've checked Python 3.8 and 3.6).

Currently, I can either have only the ellipsis (arbitrary number of arguments) or a list of argtypes but of finite length.

---

Is there a way to create the Callable in a way that is compatible across python versions and maintains the "at least one" argument criterion?

Comment: The "literal ellipsis" parts means *any* number of arguments of *any* type. That is ``Callable[..., int]`` not ``Callable[[Any, ...], int]``. Use a ``Protocol`` for more complex singatures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I annotate a callable with *args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809562/how-do-i-annotate-a-callable-with-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Protocols seem to be a way to do that.
How would I compare at runtime if the passed function follows the Protocol signature?

Comment: There are no facilities to check signature *types* at runtime. You would have to create your own, most likely based on ``inspect.signature``.

Comment: The protocol type was added with Python3.9 however it is accessible for 3.6 via the mypy package. If you write an answer I will accept it :)