# How to add python type check for a Callable with a defined argument and kwargs

Tags: python, python-typing

What I have is a function as a parameter. This function will always need to take a dictionary, and then can optionally take any number of keyword arguments. See code below for a simplified example:

```py
def my_func(func, **kwargs):
    my_map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    func(my_map, **kwargs)
```

How would I type this? I would have thought I can do the following but I get the error `"..." is not allowed in this context`

```py
def default_func(mapping: dict[str, Any]) -> list[Any]:
   # do something and return list

def my_func(
   func: Callable[[dict[str, Any], ...], list[Any]] = default_func,
   **kwargs: Any
) -> Any:
   my_map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
   func(my_map, **kwargs)
```

Is there a way to do this or do I just need to use `Callable[..., list[Any]]`?

Comment: worst case use `Any` ie `Callable[[dict[str, Any], Any]` - this discussion  might be of interest https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I annotate a callable with \*args and \*\*kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809562/how-do-i-annotate-a-callable-with-args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `typing.Concatenate` with `typing.ParamSpec`:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
RT = TypeVar("RT")


def default_func(mapping: dict[str, Any]) -> list[Any]:
    # do something and return list
    return []


def my_func(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[dict[str, Any], P], RT] = default_func,  # type: ignore
    *args: P.args,
    **kwargs: P.kwargs,
) -> RT:
    my_map = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
    return func(my_map, *args, **kwargs)
```

Few things to note though:

- `ParamSpec` requires both `args` and `kwargs` to appear in function signature
- the `default_func` is reported to be incompatible when applied as a default, even though it's compatible when applied as an argument, hence the `type: ignore` comment.