# Type mismatch python function for decorator

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm working with some Python code that utilizes decorators. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
def method1(
    a: Type[BaseClass],
    b: Callable[[Tuple[BaseClass, ...]], Callable[[Type], Type]],
    c: Tuple[BaseClass, ...],) -> Callable[[Type], Type]:
    # ... (function definition)

def example(*input: Class) -> Callable[[Type], Type]:
    return method1(Class, example, input)
```

I'm encountering a type warning in the `example` decorator, specifically in the `return method1(Class, example, input)` call for argument `example`.

The warning message I'm getting is:

```
Expected type '(Tuple[BaseClass, ...]) -> (type) -> type', got '(input: Tuple[Class, ...]) -> (type) -> type' instead
```

`Class` inherits from `BaseClass`.

I'm unsure why the type mismatch is occurring in this case. Arguments `a` and `b` don't have warnings.

Any insights on how to resolve this type mismatch to ensure the no warnings would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `method1` takes a callable that accepts a tuple, but `example` does not accept a tuple

Comment: This is a duplicate question already answered in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809562/how-do-i-annotate-a-callable-with-args-and-kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809562/how-do-i-annotate-a-callable-with-args-and-kwargs)