Type a Callable so it can take any number of string arguments, and then keyword arguments
I have a function which accepts any function such that:

it accepts any number of arguments of type str
it may accept any number of keyword arguments of any type
it returns str

Examples of acceptable function:

def func(a: str, b: str, c: str, *, foo: int) -> str
def func(a: str, b: str, *, foo: int) -> str
def func(a: str) -> str

Examples of non-acceptable functions:

def func(a: str, b: str, c: str, foo: int) -> str
def func(foo: int) -> str

How can I type this so mypy will accept it?
I've tried Callable[[str, ...], str] but mypy already rejects that, and I don't know how to add in the "kwargs of any type" part

The closest I can think of is a callback protocol with def __call__(self, *args: str, foo: int) -> str: .... However, it still does not work (playground), and it may not even be possible without an explicit union (reference).

thanks @mkrieger1. Without the **kwargs part, is it at least possible to annotate a Callable so it can accept any number of str arguments?

I don't think so, you have to use a Protocol (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809562/how-do-i-annotate-a-callable-with-args-and-kwargs).

sure, but even then, if I make a Protocol with def __call__(self, *args: str) -> str, then it only accepts functions where the signature is def func(*args: str) -> str, as opposed to, say, def func(arg_1: str, arg_2: str) -> str

If you just want positional string arguments, you can do: collections.abc.Callable[[typing_extensions.Unpack[tuple[str, ...]]], str].

Actually, I don't think your question makes sense. A callable which takes any number of string arguments and then any keywords cannot be something like def func(a: str) -> str - because that only takes 1 string argument and no keywords. Rather than "example of acceptable functions", do you mean "examples of acceptable call expressions" -> func("a", "b", "c", foo=1), func("a", "b", foo=1), etc.?

What's the problem you're solving? Why do you want such a function? You can't do anything with it maintaining type safety - at the very least, you can't call it. So this restriction sounds too artificial for python's type system: it is mostly built with real use cases in mind, not trying to support arbitrary restrictions and transformations.

The ultimate goal is to use this to make a decorator which transforms types correctly, but it might just not be possible

How do you intend to use that decorator? Please tedit] to clarify.

A common practice is to not support an arbitrary number of such arguments, but pick an upper limit and use overload to define a separate car for each number below that limit.
